# How to Load PDF file in runtime using PDF Renderer Asset in unity?

Tags: unity, rendering

Hello Guys : I am working in Unity PDF Renderer. I will purchased that Asset but i need to Know, How to load PDF file one by one in run time in File path mode but old PDF File will remove and Load new PDF file in run time. can any one help

Comment: Note that users here won't necessarily be experts on every 3rd party asset out there. Including a link to any documentation provided with the asset can help us puzzle it out with you, or you can try asking the creators of the asset themselves through a contact link or Unity forum.

Comment: I purchased that asset in Asset Store.

Comment: which version you using?